# Sequelize onDelete: 'cascade' with paranoid: true

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, sequelize.js

I have some model associations that look like this:

```
db.runt.hasMany db.runtsBudgets, { foreignKey: 'runt_id' }
db.runt.hasMany db.runtsProperties, { foreignKey: 'runt_id' }
db.runtsProperties.belongsTo db.runt, { onDelete: 'cascade' }
db.runtsBudgets.belongsTo db.runt, { onDelete: 'cascade' }
```

These models were all defined with `paranoid: true`. Given that I have a `runt` with a `runtsBudgets`, when I try to delete the `runt` like this:

`db.runt.destroy(id: 1).complete (err) ->`

The `runt` is correctly soft-deleted, but the `runtsBudgets` is not. The cascading delete works fine if I don't use `paranoid: true`, but doesn't work otherwise.

Does anyone know if sequelize even supports cascading soft-deletion? Or am I doing something completely wrong here? I've looked through their documentation on associations and `paranoid` and I'm not finding anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually a bug in pre-2.0.0 versions of `sequelize`, and was being caused by an `options` variable not actually being passed into the `bulkUpdate` call that's made when a `delete` is done on a paranoid table.

This issue has now been resolved by this [patch here.](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/2404)